# One or multiple registry.ex in an Ash project?

Tags: elixir, ash-framework

https://ash-hq.org/docs/guides/ash/latest/tutorials/get-started proposes this file structure:

```
lib/
├─ helpdesk/
│  ├─ support/
│  │  ├─ registry.ex    # <-----
│  │  ├─ resources/
│  │  │  ├─ ticket.ex
│  ├─ support.ex
```

`support` is the API here or is it `helpdesk`? I am struggling with the wording. Anyhow I understand the tutorial so that the file `registry.ex` has always to be under the `support´ directory.

### This works

My project has this file structure:

```
lib
├── feriendaten
│   ├── geo
│   │   ├── geo.ex
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── level.ex
│   │       ├── location.ex
│   │       └── school.ex
│   ├── legacy
│   │   ├── legacy.ex
│   │   └── resources
│   │       └── legacy_location.ex
│   ├── registry.ex   # <---- one file
```

The file `lib/feriendaten/registry.ex` has this content:

```elixir
defmodule Feriendaten.Registry do
  use Ash.Registry,
    extensions: [
      # This extension adds helpful compile time validations
      Ash.Registry.ResourceValidations
    ]

  entries do
    entry Feriendaten.Geo.Level
    entry Feriendaten.Geo.Location
    entry Feriendaten.Legacy.LegacyLocation
    entry Feriendaten.Geo.School
  end
end
```

That works without a problem.

### This doesn't works

According to the above tutorial the file structure should be like this (one `registry.ex` in each directory):

```
lib
├── feriendaten
│   ├── geo
│   │   ├── geo.ex
│   │   ├── registry.ex   # <- first registry.ex
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── level.ex
│   │       ├── location.ex
│   │       └── school.ex
│   ├── legacy
│   │   ├── legacy.ex
│   │   ├── registry.ex   # <- second registry.ex
│   │   └── resources
│   │       └── legacy_location.ex
```

I tried it with this code:

**lib/feriendaten/geo/registry.ex**

```elixir
defmodule Feriendaten.Geo.Registry do
  use Ash.Registry,
    extensions: [
      # This extension adds helpful compile time validations
      Ash.Registry.ResourceValidations
    ]

  entries do
    entry Feriendaten.Geo.Level
    entry Feriendaten.Geo.Location
    entry Feriendaten.Geo.School
  end
end
```

**lib/feriendaten/legacy/registry.ex**

```elixir
defmodule Feriendaten.Legacy.Registry do
  use Ash.Registry,
    extensions: [
      # This extension adds helpful compile time validations
      Ash.Registry.ResourceValidations
    ]

  entries do
    entry Feriendaten.Legacy.LegacyLocation
  end
end
```

But this results into this error:

```elixir
Compiling 4 files (.ex)
** (EXIT from #PID<0.95.0>) an exception was raised:
    ** (RuntimeError) Resources Feriendaten.Geo.Location, Feriendaten.Geo.Level must be included in the registry.
```

Is the file path of the `registry.ex` in the tutorial misleading or am I doing a mistake? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the file path will never matter for Ash Framework libraries. We make no assertion on the file name. The only thing at play here is what resources are in your registry.

Registries are just tools to list the modules available to a given api. What is not shown here, I believe, is an api module with something like this:

```
resources do
  registry Foo
  registry Bar
end
```

The problem here is that you can only have one registry per api. The second call to `registry` is simply overwriting the first one.

In Ash, to split up our application, we create multiple APIs each with their own registry. Then, to relate across api modules, you use the `api` option. I.e

```
belongs_to :owner, MyApp.Accounts.User do
  api MyApp.Accounts
end
```

If we detect a relationship to a resource and that api either: is not in the registry also, or does not have a configured api, we raise the error that you see above.